# Can't use 9999999999999999 value

Tags: java, long-integer

i have this program that encrypt using a DES key in CBC mode , i need an IV:

```
 for(double ii=0;ii<9999999999999999;ii++)
                    {

                        String IIV=String.valueOf(ii);
                        IV=String.valueOf(ii);

                        for(int x=0;x<(16-IIV.length());x++)
                        {
                          IV=("0"+IV);  
                        }

                   Encrypt.ENC(Secretkey,IV,"Hi");

                    }
```

i tried to use double and long in the for loop and i still cant initialise the value 9999999999999999 to ii since the IV should be from 0000000000000000 to 9999999999999999

Comment: Read (and include) the *actual* error message(s). Also, please be conservative with the tags - the immediate issues are not related directly to "encryption" or anything else, although you will likely encounter *other* problems with this code, which should be in their *own* questions.

Comment: the error is : "incompatible types:int cannot be converted to Long"

Comment: That's a very informative error message. Also, don't use doubles as integers (meaning whole numbers, not the data type)

Comment: this is the only clue i got @ᴋᴇʏsᴇʀ from Netbeans

Comment: `long ii` or `BigInteger` is all I can think of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i tried this:

```
for(long int i=0;i<((10e16)-1);i++)
```

it worked

Comment: "long int" worked, huh?  If you say so.

You've got an off-by-one error in there, too.

Answer (score 6):

The integer literal `9999999999999999` is too large to be represented as an `int`.  Use a `long` literal, with a `L` suffix:

```
for(double ii=0;ii<9999999999999999L;ii++)
```

By the way, that is a *long* loop.  That will run for a very long time.

Comment: still there is still an error , and yea its a long loop this is my project so far to try every value of the IV

Answer (score 4):

At 10,000 iterations per second, we're talking approximately 32,000 years to run that loop.  I think you need to rethink what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

`9999999999999999` needs 54 bits to represent, which is out of the range of a 32 bit integer. Java integers are signed, so a positive number has to be less than 2^31. You could use `long` which has a positive range of 2^63.

Comment: While true, an issue/error is directly related to the fact that Java does *not* promote "int" literals to `long` values (this promotion is done automatically in C#, so it's merely a syntax/language choice as both systems support 64-bit integers). That is, `long x = (long)9999999999999999;` is still invalid Java and results in a compiler-error: "integer number too large".